# Pushing key/value pairs into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a dictionary (dictionaryish) variable in Javascript.

```
var dict = {
  val1 : ["a", "b", "c"],
  val2 : ["d", "e", "f"],
  val3 : ["g", "h", "i"],
  ...
}
```

I want to be able to add val1, val2, val3, etc into an array and then display it in JSON

```
{
  "Configs" : [
      "val1" : ["a", "b", "c"],
      "val2" : ["d", "e", "f"],
      "val3" : ["g", "h", "i"],
   ]
}
```

Is it possible to push these key value pairs into an array? If so, how would I call these values? `arr[1].key()?`

```
arr = 
[
   {val1 : ["a", "b", "c"]},
   {val2 : ["d", "e", "f"]},
   {val3 : ["g", "h", "i"]},
]
```

Comment: The second and the third code snippets are not valid JavaScript.

Comment: @BatScream i jsut checked and it is

Comment: @Liondancer: the second snippet absolutely is not valid. I don't know where you "checked", but it just isn't.

Comment: And what do you mean by "JSON" format? What do you want the end result to be? Because nothing you've posted is JSON.

Comment: @MattBurland i was referring to the 3rd snippet and the 2nd snippet is a JSON value I wanted to give an example of. Sorry I should have been more specific

Comment: The second snippet isn't valid JavaScript or JSON.

Comment: @Liondancer: The second snippet isn't valid JSON either.

Comment: In the third array, you can access the elements like how you access a normal javascript array : arr[i].val1, but before that build a json document for each "val1",... and push them into the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you want is something like this:

```js
    var dict = {
      val1: ["a", "b", "c"],
      val2: ["d", "e", "f"],
      val3: ["g", "h", "i"],
    }

    var obj = {
      Configs: []
    };

    for (var k in dict) {
      if (dict.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        var o = {};
        o[k] = dict[k];
        obj.Configs.push(o);
      }
    }

    alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

This will give you an object that looks like this:

```
{
  "Configs" : [
      { "val1" : ["a", "b", "c"] },
      { "val2" : ["d", "e", "f"] },
      { "val3" : ["g", "h", "i"] },
   ]
}
```

If you want to be able to retrieve an item from the array with a particular key (say `val2`), then you'll have to search the array for the item that has the `val2` key. If you need that kind of access to the collection, then it's not clear why you would have converted it from a dictionary in the first place.

Comment: And to make it look more like the third code block, `obj.Config` is replaced by simply `arr`.